# format double as percentage - show all decimals?

Tags: c#, string, format

I can't find a way to format a double as a percentage showing all decimals in C# 4.0.

Using `{0:P}` has the same effect as `{0:P2}`, i.e. formatting as a percentage, showing two decimals strictly.

I finally went for substituting the problematic `{0:P}` with `{0:0.################################%}`. For my purpose, my doubles do not reach that many decimals.

Comment: As I understand you don't want traling zeroes at the right after the decimal separator. But... Do you care about globalizaion? The percentage symbol may be different, the negative format may be different, the decimal separator may be different, and so on? by the way: You should Add clarifications by editing the question

Comment: Using CultureInfo.InvariantCulture is fine by me, so no, Globalization is not an issue.

Comment: then Pengu's solution, others (so far) has trailing zeroes at the end or rounding issues.

Comment: Documentation of "P" is on: [Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

### Original Solution

Basically this is what you want to do:

```
string.Format("{0:0.############## %}", 0.1234); // 12.34 %
string.Format("{0:0.############## %}", 0.1234567); //12.34567 %
```

*note*: For decimal you would use `0.############################`.

---

**drawbacks of the alternatives**

You should notice that `0:0.00000000000000 %` leave trailing zeroes:

```
string.Format("{0:0.00000000000000 %}", 0.1234); // 12.34000000000000 %
```

Using `P14` or `NumberFormatInfo.PercentDecimalDigits` has the same behaviour. Which is good if you want to truncate the number. You may also resource to divisions, but take care of rounding.

If you want the full precission with no trailing zeroes you should use `0.############## %`.

---

### New Solution (Taking globalization into account)

You can use this method to build a custom format that matches what the default `P` formal would do, but without a fixed number of decimal places:

```
public string GetPercentFormat(CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (culture == null)
    {
        culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
    }
    NumberFormatInfo nfi = culture.NumberFormat;
    //% and . are localized by default
    var baseFormat = "0.################";
    var percentSymbol = "%";
    var negativeSign = nfi.NegativeSign; //It may be problematic
    string customFormat = string.Empty;
    switch (nfi.PercentPositivePattern)
    {
        case 1: //n%
            customFormat += baseFormat + percentSymbol;
            break;
        case 2: //%n
            customFormat += percentSymbol + baseFormat;
            break;
        case 3: //% n
            customFormat += percentSymbol + " " + baseFormat;
            break;
        case 0: //n %
        default:
            customFormat += baseFormat + " " + percentSymbol;
            break;
    }
    customFormat += ";";
    switch (nfi.PercentNegativePattern)
    {
        case 1: //-n%
            customFormat += negativeSign + baseFormat + percentSymbol;
            break;
        case 2: //-%n
            customFormat += negativeSign + percentSymbol + baseFormat;
            break;
        case 3: //%-n
            customFormat += percentSymbol + negativeSign + baseFormat;
            break;
        case 4: //%n-
            customFormat += percentSymbol + baseFormat + negativeSign;
            break;
        case 5: //n-%
            customFormat += baseFormat + negativeSign + percentSymbol;
            break;
        case 6: //n%-
            customFormat += baseFormat + percentSymbol + negativeSign;
            break;
        case 7: //-% n
            customFormat += negativeSign + percentSymbol + " " + baseFormat;
            break;
        case 8: //n %-
            customFormat += baseFormat + " " + percentSymbol + negativeSign;
            break;
        case 9: //% n-
            customFormat += percentSymbol + " " + baseFormat + negativeSign;
            break;
        case 10: //% -n
            customFormat += percentSymbol + " " + negativeSign + baseFormat;
            break;
        case 11: //n- %
            customFormat += baseFormat + negativeSign + " " + percentSymbol;
            break;
        case 0: //-n %
        default:
            customFormat += negativeSign + baseFormat + " " + percentSymbol;
            break;
    }
    return customFormat;
}
```

*Note*: it may be worth to implement this using `StringBuilder`.

Use it like this:

```
void Main()
{
    var customFormat = GetPercentFormat(null);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:"+ customFormat + "}", 0.1234));
}
```

Output:

```
12.34 %
```

You can also use an alternative `CultureInfo`:

```
void Main()
{
    var culture = new CultureInfo("quz-BO"); //Quechua (Bolivia)
    var customFormat = GetPercentFormat(culture);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format(culture, "{0:"+ customFormat + "}", 0.1234));
}
```

Output:

```
%12,34
```

The resulting format from `GetPercentFormat` is *almost* fully localized. It will take into account custom negative and positive formats for the given `CultureInfo`. Note: this is *almost* fully localized because groups ([NumberFormatInfo.PercentGroupSeparator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.percentgroupseparator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) and group sizes ([NumberFormatInfo.PercentGroupSizes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.percentgroupsizes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) are not being used.

Answer (score 1):

The "P" format specifier uses the current culture info, you can get the default number of digits after the decimal point using [NumberFormatInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currentinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [PercentDecimalDigits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.percentdecimaldigits%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
NumberFormatInfo nfi = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat;
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} PercentDecimalDigits", nfi.PercentDecimalDigits));
```

You can extend this number by formatting with:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Value: {0:P4}.", 0.123456));
```

Or calculate the percentage yourself.

Answer (score 1):

> Using CultureInfo.InvariantCulture is fine by me, so no, Globalization
>   is not an issue

Well, then:

```
double myDouble = (double)1 / 3; // 0.3333333...
string asString = string.Format("{0} %", myDouble * 100);
```

Comment: I agree, only I am using a web framework which constrains me to provide standard format strings, and formatting is left for an external component to do.

Answer (score 0):

The decimal type has a precision of around 30 digits. So there is no way to "really" show unlimited decimal numbers.

But take a look at the '#' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx

Comment: Could you add an example in your answer?

Comment: @Theraot take a look at shree.pat18´s answer. I thought something smiliar like "{0:#.##%}" (build the "#.###....#" in a loop or so) Its no good answer compared to the others but would solve the problem. Anyways 30 # would always be enough cause thats the precision of a decimal

Comment: @Pengu I removed my answer as I realised I had misread the question. I agree with your point.

Answer (score 0):

{0:P} is strictly restricted to 2 decimal places

You will have to hard code decimal value if you want to use .

Other way in my view is like this

double valueToDisplay = (10.0 /7.0);
  var percentValue=   String.Format("{0}%", valueToDisplay );